# Clarification about the iota function of SHA-3

Tags: sha-3, keccak

I am trying to implement SHA-3 using [this document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) and have a question about the iota step.

This step consists in a single XOR between the central (0, 0) lane of the state (illustration of the state p.8 if needed) and a round constant. In other terms:

```
for z in [0, w[:
    let new_state(0, 0, z) = state(0, 0, z) ^ RC[z]
```

where RC is viewed as a bit string.

The first round constant of the first round is 1, thus only one bit will be changed. As it can be seen in this [document](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA3-512_1600.pdf) providing test vectors, we have in round #0:

```
After Chi
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...
After Iota
    01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... (following is equal to above)
```

However, there is something I don't understand: the bit that is changed in those test vectors is the eighth one, but our round constant is a 1 written on w-bits. If $w=8$ (implying a 200-bits message), everything is fine, but in the previous link, we have a message of 1600 bits, hence $w=64$. How can XOR-ing this 64-bits 0...01 change the eighth bit of the lane ?

EDIT: I will add my code below (it is still work in progress):

```
class Keccak(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = 6
        self.w = pow(2, self.l)

        self.state = [[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)] for z in range(self.w)]
        self.tmp_state = [[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)] for z in range(self.w)]


    def init_state(self, S):
        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                for z in range(self.w):
                    self.set_state(x, y, z, int(S[self.w*(5*y + x) + z], 2))

    def init_tmp_state(self):
        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                for z in range(self.w):
                    self.set_tmp_state(x, y, z, 0)


    def index_processing(self, x, y, z):
        return (z % self.w, (y + 2) % 5, (x + 2) % 5)
        

    def get_state(self, x, y, z):
        x, y, z = self.index_processing(x, y, z)
        return self.state[x][y][z]

    def set_state(self, x, y, z, v):
        x, y, z = self.index_processing(x, y, z)
        self.state[x][y][z] = v


    def get_tmp_state(self, x, y, z):
        x, y, z = self.index_processing(x, y, z)
        return self.tmp_state[x][y][z]

    def set_tmp_state(self, x, y, z, v):
        x, y, z = self.index_processing(x, y, z)
        self.tmp_state[x][y][z] = v


    def state_to_string(self):
        bit_string = []
        for y in range(5):
            for x in range(5):
                for z in range(self.w):
                    bit_string.append(str(self.get_state(x, y, z)))

        return ''.join(bit_string)


    def rc(self, t):
        if t % 255 == 0:
            return 1

        R = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        for i in range(1, (t % 255) + 1):
            R = [0] + R
            R[0] ^= R[8]
            R[4] ^= R[8]
            R[5] ^= R[8]
            R[6] ^= R[8]
            R = R[:8]

        return R[0]


    def iota(self, i):
        RC = [0 for j in range(self.w)]
        for j in range(self.l + 1):
            RC[pow(2, j) - 1] = self.rc(j + 7*i)

        for z in range(self.w):
            self.set_state(0, 0, z, self.get_state(0, 0, z) ^ RC[z])




def test_iota():
    initial_state = "0000000000000000D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D20000000000000000E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E83A3A3A3A3A3A3A3A535353535353535300000000000000001D1D1D1D1D1D1D1D4E4E4E4E4E4E4E4E00000000000000004141414141414141E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E80000000000000000414141414141414126262626262626261D1D1D1D1D1D1D1D0000000000000000474747474747474718181818181818184747474747474747E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E835353535353535350000000000000000AFAFAFAFAFAFAFAF1212121212121212"
    initial_state = bin(int(initial_state, 16))[2:].zfill(1600)

    keccak = Keccak()
    keccak.init_state(initial_state)
    keccak.iota(0)
    result = keccak.state_to_string()

    correct_result = "0100000000000000D2D2D2D2D2D2D2D20000000000000000E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E83A3A3A3A3A3A3A3A535353535353535300000000000000001D1D1D1D1D1D1D1D4E4E4E4E4E4E4E4E00000000000000004141414141414141E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E80000000000000000414141414141414126262626262626261D1D1D1D1D1D1D1D0000000000000000474747474747474718181818181818184747474747474747E8E8E8E8E8E8E8E835353535353535350000000000000000AFAFAFAFAFAFAFAF1212121212121212"
    correct_result = bin(int(correct_result, 16))[2:].zfill(1600)

    print("\tIota:\t" + str(result == correct_result))
    
    print(result[0:64] + '\n\n' + correct_result[0:64])
```

The test prints:

```
    Iota:   False
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Figure 2, the position of indexes is not standard. [0,0,1] is the center of the front slice. So when printing this will be printed.

Comment: I also thought I may have messed up the indexing, but I tested my string_to_state and state_to_string functions using sections 3.1.2 and 3.1.3, and they seemed correct. But I also don't think the issue could come from anywhere else than there. I will edit to add my code. Additionally, in section 3.1.3, the bit string resulting from the state is first constructed by concatenating state(0, 0, 0) to state(0, 0, 63) : doesn't this still mean that the bit changed and later printed is the eighth one, in state(0, 0, 7) ?

Comment: A thought that just occured to me: maybe this is just a silly endianness problem ? But the pi and khi functions I wrote both pass their tests and give the expected result, so I don't know about changing the endianness. I will try just in case.

Comment: Well, seems the answer was that it wasn't endianness per se, but rather "bitwise endianness" where the bits have to be taken in reverse order. Weird. But I should have read the standard more carefully.

Comment: One should read the whole document before starting.

Comment: You can answer your question, that is ok!